# Дополнение строки нулями

Tags: linux, shell

Кусок кода 
Есть переменные. Они могут быть однозначные двузначные и трехзначные.

busNumber=`cat $dir/busnum`
devNumber=`cat $dir/devnum`

Строка выполнения должна принимать только трехзначные значения
./usbr "/dev/bus/usb/$busNumber/$devNumber"

Подскажите решение как сделать так, чтобы если переменная однозначная то перед ней добавляется два нуля, если двухзначная то - один ноль, если трехзначная то ничего.

Comment: printf %03d число

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
/dev/bus/usb/`printf %03d $busNumber`/`printf %03d $devNumber`
```

Answer (score 2):

> Строка выполнения должна принимать только трехзначные значения ./usbr "/dev/bus/usb/$busNumber/$devNumber"

```
$ busNumber=8
$ devNumber=9
$ ./usbr $(printf "/dev/bus/usb/%.3d/%.3d" $busNumber $devNumber)
```

подробнее о встроенной команде printf можно почитать, например, [здесь](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf).